# Is It possible to communication between Android and PC using USB

Tags: android, notepad

Is there any source code for sending message from android and it will show on PC Notepad? And if I write some message on PC'S notepad then it will show on Android Device. I am new in Android.

Comment: It's possible but you are talking about some pretty advanced stuff. Stack Overflow is really meant for specific help when you get stuck, not "give me the sourcez". You would be best checking out http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=tutorial first.

Answer (score 0):

USB on Android [can be programmatically accessed](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/index.html), however your case is not supported: USB device mode (PC is a host) can not be programmaticaly controled.